# File transfer over HTTP using camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to set up a Camel route for transferring files over HTTP. I'm also trying to understand the concept as I'm new to this.

When I code something like below, does that mean I'm routing a simple message over HTTP? Could I call Jetty the consumer in this case? I'm able to run the below code and call the browser and see the message successfully.

```
    from("jetty://http://localhost:32112/greeting")
    .setBody(simple("Hello, world!"));
```

However, I want to send a simple message(eventually an XML) over HTTP following which I would want to save it on disk and analyse it further. Should the code like below work?

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("direct:start", "This is a test message");
from("direct:start")
.to("jetty://localhost:32112/greeting");

from("jetty://http://localhost:32112/greeting")
.to("direct:end");
```

Should I be not using direct:start here for parsing XMLs?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: How will you be interacting with Camel? Will a browser be sending something to the jetty endpoint? Will it be a program? If it a browser, then the data that will come in will be just like any other http: query-parms, headers, message-body.The Camel documentation talks about multi-part forms, if that's what you need.http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html

Comment: Are the XML files being read from the local file system or from a web service?

Comment: @MrGravity  
The XML files are to be read from a webservice. I thought that creating the jetty component is like creating a web service. But I did not understand how to set data or send the files through such a component! For example, I'm able to set a simple String message by using the setBody method. What do I do if I have to send an XML likewise?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create your routes and start your context. Then you can send messages via your template.

The route could look like this

        `from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:32112/greeting")
                .routeId("xml-converter-route").autoStartup(false)
                .bean(xmlConverterBean, "convertXmlMethodToBeCalledInBean()")
        ;`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to transfer data and nothing else use restlet or netty-http4. More lightweight than jetty.

```
from("restlet:/http://localhost:32112/greeting").convertBodyTo(String.class).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "filetransfer", "log of body: ${body} and headers ${headers}").to("file://C:/test?fileName=body.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a camel test which may help you understand how these components work.

```
public class CamelRESTExampleTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CamelRESTExampleTest.class);

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {

                // Create a service listening on port 8080
                from("restlet:http://localhost:8080/xmlFileService?restletMethod=post")
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                String rawXML = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                                LOG.info("rawXML=" + rawXML);
                            }
                        });

                // Read files from the local directory and send to the service.
                // Create a test.xml file in this directory and it will be read in
                from("file:src/test/resources/data?noop=true")
                        .to("restlet:http://localhost:8080/xmlFileService?restletMethod=post");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        // Give the route time to complete
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
}
```